# Including pybind11 cmake files with Hunter

Tags: cmake, pybind11, cmake-modules

I am using Hunter to manage dependencies of my project.
One of them is `pybind11`
It has been installed correctly and I can use it in my code.
However when building my project with CMake I need to use some cmake function provided by `pybind11` in some cmake files.
These are located in `pybind11_DIR`
How can I include them ?

Before I was used to only do that `add_subdirectory(pybind11)` to have everything included.

Thanks

Comment: After the `hunter_add_package(pybind11)` and `find_package(pybind11)`, just use the `pybind11_add_module(...)` function; it works.

Comment: indeed... thx. If I want to use `target_link_directories` with `pybind11_add_module` how can i do that ?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#pybind11-add-module)